# Installed torch in conda env and activated the env but got No module named torch

Tags: pytorch, conda, virtualenv

I successfully installed torch in conda env, but when I'm tring to use torch, I got `No module named torch`

I used `pip list | grep torch`, and got:

- torch              2.1.1
- torchaudio         2.1.1
- torchvision        0.16.1

and also, I deactivated the conda env and then activated it again to make sure I use the env.
But when I tried to `import torch`, I still got `No module named torch`.

Could anyone can help to solve this problem?

Comment: can you check `which pip` to see where the pip installs packages. It should be in the conda environment that you are using. Needless to say, that a conda env must be activated before installing any packages via pip in that env.

Comment: I suppose this issue is caused by the IDE(Pycharm) I use for I restart the IDE the error goes away. But I don't know why it happens. :(

Comment: check if the conda environment is activate when you get the error. Oherwise you can activate it by `conda activate your_env`

Comment: I was surely useing conda env, and my terminal will show me which env I am using. And to make sure it is not caused by the terminal, I restarted the terminal and activated the env again, but also got this error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either

- not installed torch in the environment you thought you had
- or you are not using the environment you think you use.

I made you a screenshot where you can follow the very same steps to activate an run torch, maybe it helps you to find the error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using the right `python`.

Most venvs usually have `[virtual-env]/bin/python` and `[virtual-env]/bin/python3`.

Try activating the shell with `python3` or running your test with `python3` if you're not doing so now.

Then setup aliases if you want.